# Format Strings in YML Files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, yaml

1. Im using a YML file for language conversion and i cant figure out how to format text within this file. For instance if i say

   `#fourthScreenFive: "В this is string 1 \n this is string 2"`

the `\n` does not work. Would anyone know how i can get this done?

1. I also want to be able to center some strings and again /t or any other command doesn't work. Would anyone have any documentation?

I found this : http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#three_trailing_newlines_in_literals but it doesnt have much information on strings that are already strings " ".

```
 fourthScreenSeven: |+     
                 Оно оказалось настолько вкусным что с тех,      
                 пор мы никогда не меняли рецепт
```

Comment: How are you **outputting** the string? _puts_ in the console will respect the new line if it's inside quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add extra lines in a string using YAML you could use a yaml like that:

```
fourthScreenSeven: |
  Оно оказалось настолько вкусным что с тех,
  пор мы никогда не меняли рецепт

fourthScreenFive: |
  В this is string 1
  this is string 2
```

Using the following ruby code:

```
p YAML.load(IO.read('yaml.yml'))
```

You will get this result:

```
{"fourthScreenSeven"=>
    "Оно оказалось настолько вкусным что с тех,\nпор мы никогда не меняли рецепт\n",
    "fourthScreenFive"=>"В this is string 1\nthis is string 2\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a YAML file in Visual Studio Code and I found that I can get line  breaks by using \n\r but only if the string is in quotes. So like this:

"В this is string 1 \n\r this is string 2"